# What does a beginner need to know to build a programmable heater based on resistance heating?

Tags: heat

To build a programmable deep fryer, as a learning project for more serious checmical reactors, I need to build a programmable heat source that can be controlled in response to sensor readings and a schedule. I'm a programmer and I have some metalworking skills that I am currently expanding on, but my knowledge on electronics is basic at best.

I'm pretty much in love with induction heating, but I was advised on [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59989/what-does-a-beginner-need-to-know-to-build-an-inductive-heater) that it might not be the wisest choice to start with, so let's try resistance heating first.

Comment: How far apart are the desired oil temperature and the oil's ignition temperature?  I would strongly advise against attempting such a project without a safety-shutdown mechanism which is 100% reliable in "danger" situations, but which a properly-functioning control system would never trip.

Comment: More soon - but start with this : http://makeprojects.com/Project/Sous+Vide+Immersion+Cooker/471/1#.UTd7HdbRh8E

Comment: And browse [these images](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=diy+temperature+controller&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=iXs3UejCBIi0kgX6i4GwCw&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=2133&bih=1201) which each link to a web page. Hover over each to see if it seems relevant. Mor later. 6:25am here. Almost bedtime :-)

Comment: @HannoFietz even I wanted to build this thing, I saw your Inductive Heating question also... I understand the condescending attitude from community is for our own safety but could you guys direct us to learning sources instead of handing down ready-made stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, a beginner doesn't need to know much at all. You can buy the control system off the shelf.

[image: Industrial Temperature Controller]

This is an Industrial Temperature Controller. You simply connect up the temperature sensor, an solid state relay (they often come with both of these). Let it run through its learning cycle. Then you program in the temperature you want, and watch it automatically control your deep fat to the temperature you want.

They're available for very little money on [eBay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_nkw=temperature%20controller). They solid state relay it comes with is good for 10A (2.5kW heater).